# finding the max value in a list and adding 1

Tags: list

I have created some code to read data from a text file that has a list of sequential number. The user is prompted to see if they are a teacher or student(I have only written for a student) When they enter student the numbers in the text file are read to the list "log" and the maximum value is found. The code should then add 1 to this value. The user is them asked their name and this along with the new value is written to the original text file. so that the is a list of students with unique id number. The code works fine and add new students with sequential id number up to the number 10 but then stops and will only add the number 10. I suspect the int(max(list)+1 is the problem.

```
log=[];
Input=input("student or teacher?")
if Input =="student":
        file=open("numbers.txt","r")
        for line in file:
                split=line.split(":")
                log.append(split[0]);
        file.close()
        print(log)
else:
        print()    
number=int(max(log))+1
name=input("what is your name?")
file=open("numbers.txt","a")
file.write(number+":"+name+"\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Don't worry I sorted it I turned the list of value into a string before finding the max value

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rephrase your question to make it clearer and more readable.
What language is that? (You can edit the post to add tags)